# wp_head conflicts with other jQuery scripts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

conflicts with two of the other jQuery scripts when moved right at the top straight after the

```
<head> section
```

and this only happens in the Products page.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?> conflicts with jQzoom.js and Navigation/jquery1.js on Products page.
```

When I put

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

above

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jq/jquery.jqzoom-core.js">
```

then jQzoom stops working on the products page and when I put if before Navigation/jquery1.js then Navigation stops working on Products page.

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/navigation/jquery1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>.
```

Everything works fine when

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

is right at the end before the

```
</head> section.
```

I need

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

right at the top straight after  section due to SEO .

Here's the link to the site that I'm working on http://www.nsmmusic.com and the issue happens to be on this page http://www.nsmmusic.com/products/digital-jukeboxes/icon-lite/ (Thanks in advance.)

Comment: How can a PHP function conflict with a javascript function? The issue is of course that you should always include your scripts with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and not just echo them out!

Comment: It's not the php that's conflicting, it's the javascript that wp_head is loading. Make sure that jQuery is being loaded and that it's not conflicting with other scripts.

Comment: Please, take no offense, by my `<head>` is spinning... You may want to check how the theme and the plugin are doing their enqueue.

Comment: @adeneo - thanks for your help I have added most of the .js files using wp_enqueue_script function and have resolved the issue.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan - Thanks using the wp_enqueue_script function has resolved the issue. :)

Comment: @brasofilo - ahaha yeah your right I ahve checked and none of the plugins were clashing infact it were the none plugin files that caused the havoc. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid asset conflicts is by properly enquing the files. To do this you must use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

a good way to do this is to put it as part of a function in your functions.php file like so

1. create a function
2. insert `wp_register_script` into the function
3. then insert `wp_enqeue_script` into the function
4. use add_action(), to initlize the enqueue-ing process

---

so -

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_register_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'scriptyouwillwaittobeloaded' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

---

In this example the function `load_scripts()` would then be called in the header.php file. Take a look at [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) as well to get a better understanding of the arguments for that as well, but in summary -

first argument: is the name you want to use as reference to this script

second argument: is the actual link to the script

third argument: is the script that you want to load before this script (the script you want to wait for before this script loads)

---

and for wp_enqueue_script, the argument is merely a reference to the name (the first argument of wp_register_script)

---

**the add_action function arguments:**

first argument: the function you are "hooking" into

second argument: the function you created that will be "hooked"

Comment: thanks for your help with detailed information it helped a lot :) really appreciate your support :) I am posting the answer below:

Answer (score 1):

I have added most of my conflicting jQuery scripts using the following method below:

```
function et_load_my_scripts(){
if ( !is_admin() ){
    $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation', $template_dir . '/js/navigation/jquery1.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('navigation1', $template_dir . '/js/navigation/nav_touch.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqzoom', $template_dir . '/js/jq/jquery.jqzoom-core.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

}
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

$et_gf_enqueue_fonts = array();
$et_gf_heading_font = sanitize_text_field( et_get_option( 'heading_font', 'none' ) );
$et_gf_body_font = sanitize_text_field( et_get_option( 'body_font', 'none' ) );

if ( 'none' != $et_gf_heading_font ) $et_gf_enqueue_fonts[] = $et_gf_heading_font;
if ( 'none' != $et_gf_body_font ) $et_gf_enqueue_fonts[] = $et_gf_body_font;

if ( ! empty( $et_gf_enqueue_fonts ) ) et_gf_enqueue_fonts( $et_gf_enqueue_fonts ); }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'et_load_my_scripts' );
```

Thanks for helping :)